# Can I use customized set of training data to train Microsoft text analytics as customized version?

Tags: sentiment-analysis, text-analytics-api

Microsoft text analytics provides out-of-box feature for sentiment analysis.

However, if I would use sentiment analysis for different situations such as restaurant comment, mobile phone suggestion, travelling adviser, those scenario and background are different.

If I would like to optimizes the reply for each situation,
theoretically, I can bring my data set to train the engine for specified purpose.

Can I input my data set to Microsoft text analytics to train a specified purpose sentiment analysis service? or I can just only use the fixed default API as general service only?

Comment: I don't think you can train Text Analytics API with your custom data. Have explored other API's like LUIS? What about using a Bot?

Comment: Thank for your opinion. I am not familiar with LUIS and I will try to study. In fact, I would like to use the text analytics API as one of back end engine for the chat bot. Many discussion forums in the Internet has suggested to have a own domain set of trained data/model for text analytics. I can generate my set of domain data. Now, I am trying to study text mining API in python to train with my data to provide as a customized API.

Answer (score 2):

Not today, thanks for the feedback though. This is an area that we are currently investigating.

Thanks!

Luis Cabrera

Text Analytics Program Manager - 
Microsoft.